# In this aquponic tank, what are these three plants and could they be killing my beta fish?

Tags: botany, ichthyology, nitrogen-cycle

I have a small aquaponic fish tank. In the tank there are two unknown types of water plants from a local pet store and the top there are three air plants from a local garden center. This tank was setup ~2 months ago and at this point tests low for ammonia, nitrate, and nitrite it also is within limits (as set by the aquarium water test strips) for PH (~7.9), hardness, and alkalinity. As far as I understand it, the nitrogen cycle and bacteria bed of this tank is alive and well. Both the water and air plants grow voraciously.

[image]

Here are the plants themselves along with their root systems. The best I remember the left was labeled as "Decorative Pepper (Hot)" and after eating one the first day I can confirm they are extremely spicy.

[image]

The second day after setting up this tank I added a single male beta to the tank. Provided it is a hardy air breathing fish I assumed it would do well while the bacteria bed setup. Though, after ~1 week the fish had died. I assumed it (Bubble Bob) was just a sickly fish from the local pet store. I wanted a few more weeks just to ensure the bacteria bed had set up and recently added another beta (Beta Bernie). I bought Bernie from a local tropical fish store and made sure to select the most lively one I could find. I assume this store takes much better care of their fish than the local big chain pet store.

A day after adding Bernie to this tank he became very sluggish and layed on the bottom, only moving to get air, not wanting to feed. This went one for a second day. Two days ago I got a small cut, added some tap water (the same water used to fill the tank), some dechlorinator, and put Bernie in it and floated the cup in the tank (which is heated). After a day Bernie popped back to life.

---

From this (same water, only difference being the plants) my assumption is that one of the air plants I purchased is potentially poisoning my betas. **Can you identify these three air plants? Are there any species of air plants which are known to release chemicals that hurt fish?**

Comment: Consider posting this to https://pets.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I went back and fourth between here and pets. I figured if anything I could identify the plants here. Then ask pets if the types of plants are known to hurt fish.

Comment: this is a good fit over at pets but you will need to give a lot more information about your water and tank setup.like the results of your last water test, PH-AMMONIA-NITRITE.i will need information about how long you cycled your tank before adding fish.if anybody here can identify the plants you have it will help diagnose your problem.a better plant to use in your filter is watercress it is one of the best plants for removal of exess nutrients and it is eddible.

Comment: you say in your question"The second day after setting up this tank"does this mean you did not cycle the tank at all? please take a look here https://www.fishlore.com/NitrogenCycle.htm

Comment: If I'm right, the middle plant looks like some kind of croton plant. Every part of a croton is poisonous, including the roots. Capsaicin (from pepper) is a strong topical irritant, but I have no clue how much is released by the roots. If it is, I don't doubt it could kill a fish. The remaining plant is a begonia, which is (iirc) edible and pretty tasty, but does contain oxalic acid in flowers and stem. Don't know about roots. So, you have two definitely suspicious plants and a maybe. Not good.